# How to reply to "where I am from" in spanish?

Tags: traducción, gramática, gentilicio

How to politely reply in Spanish when someone asks this?

> ¿De dónde eres?

Is the statement bellow correct?

> Yo de France

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you live in France, You can say

**Yo soy de Francia.**

Or

**Soy de Francia.**

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porque respondería: 

***"Yo soy de France."***

Dejando a un lado que el *"yo"* no es obligatorio, la forma correcta seria:

***"Soy de Francia."***

Comment: I would even remove "Soy". ¿De donde eres? De Salamanca. I never used "Soy de"

Answer (score 3):

Or rather "Soy de Francia", to give the country's name in Spanish as well. For France the difference is not so big that it wouldn't be understood but it gets more important with places like Germany (Alemania) or the US (Estados Unidos) :)

Answer (score 2):

**Question:**

> *¿De dónde eres?*

**Reply:**

> *"Soy de Francia." - "I'm from France."*

If you prefer to say that you're from Paris

> *"Soy Parisino." - "I'm parisian."*

Or

> *"Soy de Paris." - "I'm from Paris."*

Comment: Creo que lo correcto sería ***I'm a Parisian***

Comment: @Jdamian either would be correct although your version is probably more common.

Answer (score 1):

"Soy de Francia" sounds a bit artificial to be honest.

I would choose:

> Vengo de Francia

or

> Soy francés (male)
>
> Soy francesa (female)